# Free jqGrid - callback functions on filterToolbar are not being called

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Example is at [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13582dh7/3/) (look for the text "Example for Filter with callback function")

This deceleration seems to have no effect on beforeClear & beforeSearch:

```
$(nameOfGrid).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, searchOperators: true, defaultSearch : "cn",beforeClear: function() {alert(1)}, beforeSearch: function() {alert(1);}});
```

I placed the "alert(1)" just to see if something popsup, but it doesn't seems like it is triggered when I filter or clean the filter.

I see this since 4.9.0, but also on latest as the example shows.

Appreciate your help,

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem: the usage of `filterToolbar` **more as once**:

```
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true});
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',{...});
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, searchOperators: true, defaultSearch : "cn",beforeClear: function() {alert(1)}, beforeSearch: function() {alert(1);}});
```

If one just comments the first call of `filterToolbar` one will get working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/13582dh7/4/

If you really need to recreate the filter then you should first call `destroyFilterToolbar` before calling `filterToolbar` the next time.

I would additionally recommend you to clean up your code to make it shorter and better readable. You can for example remove unneeded `<div id="jqGridPager"></div>`, replace `pager: "#jqGridPager"` to `pager: true` and remove `"#jqGridPager"` parameter from all calls of `navGrid` and `navButtonAdd`.

You should consider to move the searching options of `navGrid` and `filterToolbar` in `searching` parameter of jqGrid.

Even more important would be remove all hidden column from `colModel`, which you don't plan to display the user and to use `additionalPropertries` instead. It's strictly recommended to use column templates in `colModel`.

After reducing the code and making it more readable and will will never spend the time for such problems like calling of `filterToolbar` twice with different parameters.